# Como posso gerar um cmakelist equivalente ao meu Makefile

Tags: c, libcurl, makefile, cmake

Tenho um Makefile que está assim e funciona para o que eu quero.

```
all:
    gcc -c curl_code.c -lcurl
    gcc -o Sete_Cliques curl_code.o main.c -lcurl
    gcc -o Sete_Cliques_Serial curl_code.o sete_cliques_serial.c -lcurl
    gcc -o Sete_Cliques_Threads curl_code.o sete_cliques_threads.c -lcurl

serial:
    gcc -c curl_code.c -lcurl
    gcc -o Sete_Cliques_Serial curl_code.o sete_cliques_serial.c -lcurl

threads:
    gcc -c curl_code.c -lcurl
    gcc -o Sete_Cliques_Threads curl_code.o sete_cliques_threads.c -lcurl

clean:
    rm curl_code.o
    rm Sete_Cliques
```

Porém, estou usando a IDE CLion e não estou conseguindo compilar, segue o arquivo CMakeLists.txt atual, preciso gerar um equivalente ao Makefile acima

```
project(t3)
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -lcurl")

add_executable(curl_code.o curl_code.c)
add_executable(Sete_Cliques curl_code.o main.c)
add_executable(Sete_Cliques_Serial curl_code.o sete_cliques_serial.c)
add_executable(Sete_Cliques_Threads curl_code.o sete_cliques_threads.c)
```

Alguma ideia? Obrigado.

Dá erro na hora de encontrar as referências para o código que está em curl_code.h

```
Scanning dependencies of target Sete_Cliques
[ 50%] Linking C executable Sete_Cliques
CMakeFiles/Sete_Cliques.dir/main.c.o: In function `main':
/home/joao/main.c:29: undefined reference to `curl_global_cleanup'
```

Answer (score 0):

O CMakeLists.txt que você mostrou não bate com o Makefile...

Não sei como o CLion trabalha com cmake, mas um CMakeLists.equivalente ao Makefile seria algo assim (deixei só o essencial):

```
project(t3)
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -lcurl")
add_executable(Sete_Cliques Sete_Cliques.c curl_code.cpp curl_code.h)
```

Nem sei se vai funcionar, depende do seu ambiente, mas o CMakeLists.txt equivalente ao Makefile é esse aí

Comment: Oi amigo, não funcionou. Editei a pergunta e adicionei o erro de compilação. Obrigado